# indexOf Multiple arguments

Tags: jquery

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if (! (pathname.indexOf('edit') > -1) ) {
  // Do stuff...
}
```

In the above example I am negating and only running the JS on pages that DO NOT include 'edit', I want to change it to accept multiple arguments, for example, "edit", "delete", "admin", "settings".

Whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if (["edit", "delete", "admin"].some(x => pathname.indexOf(x) > -1)) {
    // ...
}
```

Without arrow function for older browsers

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname,
    isSpecialPath = ["edit", "delete", "admin"].some(function(x) { return pathname.indexOf(x) > -1; });

if (isSpecialPath) {
    // ...
}
```

[`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): *The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.*

Comment: Nice, but uses modern features, so will depend on the browser (doesn't work in IE11)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill

Comment: @freedomn-m `.some()` is available since IE9. And the arrow function is easy to replace with a "normal" function.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the `=>`, not `.some()`, just adding comment as a warning incase someone tried it and just got "Syntax error" and didn't know why.

Comment: @freedomn-m I've added a version without an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop an see if anything is found and do what you want afterwards.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var names = ["edit", "delete", "admin", "settings"];
var found = false;

for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ) {
    if( pathname.indexOf(names[i]) > -1 ) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if( !found ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to test for multiple values, eg:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

var textToSearchFor = /(edit)|(delete)|(ADDMORE)/;

if (path.match(textToSearchFor) == null) {
  //Entered Text not available
  //alert("Not available");
}
else {
   //Entered Text available
   //alert("Available");
}
```

Reference : [How to search for multiple texts in a string, using java script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851094/how-to-search-for-multiple-texts-in-a-string-using-java-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```js
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if((/edit|delete|admin|settings/i).test(pathname))
{
    console.log("exists");
}
else
{
    console.log("not exists");
}
```