# Words exists in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check the words exist in string using javascript OR jquery.

For ex
String: I need to Visit W3Schools
if I check "need w3school"==> True
if I check "need go w3school"==> False
if I check "w3schools visit"==> True
if I check "need go "==> False

It can be multiple word like 1,2 or more than 2.
In short it should return "TRUE" if all the words exist in string otherwise "FALSE". Doesn't matter the sequence.

```
var dat=[];
if(str.indexOf($('#search').val()) != -1){
    dat[] = {name:str};
}
```

Comment: trying again eh....

Comment: `dat.push( {name:str} )` maybe?

Comment: @epascarello with code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911053/regular-expression-to-match-all-words-in-a-query-in-any-order?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Currently duplicate of [Contain word from whole string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842353/contain-word-from-whole-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```js
let str = "I need to Visit W3Schools";
str = str.toLowerCase();

function check(s) {
  return s.toLowerCase().split(" ").every(x => str.includes(x));
}
console.log(check("need w3school"));
console.log(check("need go w3school"));
console.log(check("w3schools visit"));
console.log(check("need go "));
```